# The SPListItem provided is not compatible with a Publishing Page

Tags: page-layout, splistitem, publishing-page

How can I save or check in my `Home.aspx` pagelayout?

Whenever I try to save or check in my `Home.aspx` pagelayout welcome page I get the following error.

```
Invalid SPListItem. The SPListItem provided is not compatible with a Publishing Page.
```

And this:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingPage.GetPublishingPage(SPListItem sourceListItem) +303
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.PublishingPageStateControl.RaisePostBackEventForPageRouting(String eventArgument, SPRibbonCommandHandler control, RaisePostBackEventDelegate raisePostBackEventDelegate) +110
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.PublishingPageSaveAndStopEditHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +134
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +29
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2981
```

I have created `home.aspx` as a new pagelayout as a welcome page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to see your code, but you can try this one.
I think this would do the trick.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://myservier"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        PublishingSite pSite = new PublishingSite(site);
        SPContentType ctype = pSite.ContentTypes["MyWelcomePage"];
        PageLayoutCollection pageLayouts = pSite.GetPageLayouts(ctype, true);
        PageLayout pageLayout = pageLayouts["/_catalogs/masterpage/PageLayout.aspx"];
        PublishingWeb pWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
        PublishingPageCollection pPages = pWeb.GetPublishingPages();
        PublishingPage pPage = pPages.Add("home.aspx", pageLayout);
        SPListItem newpage = pPage.ListItem;
        newpage["Title"] = "Page added programmatically";
        newpage.Update();

        newpage.File.CheckIn("CheckIn programmatically");
        newpage.File.Publish("Publish programmatically");
    }
```

Good luck.

Comment: Please forgive my stupidity - where do I need to place this code?

Comment: Did you create your home.aspx page programmatically? or by using the SharePoint UI?

Comment: I created it with Sharepoint Designer

Comment: Try to deactivate and reactivate the SharePoint Server Publishing site feature

Comment: I have tried that - it didn't seem to work ...

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it seems you created the Page Layout using SharePoint Designer.

Can you try to re-create the Page Layout using **SharePoint Design Manager?**

Tutorial: [How to: Create a page layout in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822368.aspx)

Comment: Water, welcome to SharePoint StackExchange. One of the standards we try to keep is adding at least an over-view of the steps in an answer rather than just offering a link as frequently blog posts and sites move or get deleted. That might not be the case with an MSDN page, but at least and over-view helps improve the quality of our community.